# How can i edit a Django form in a template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth) to handle authentication in my Django app. Now, i'd like to edit the login form's appearance, but i'm having some troubles finding the HTML file where the form is located.

[image]

For example, i would like to move 'Username' and 'Password' inside the form, make it a little bigger and some other stuff. How can i do it? I've tried to look into the HTML templates but i haven't found anything. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439153/django-auth-where-to-put-custom-templates) is relevant

Answer (score 0):

You can always override the templates of a third app. Let's call your main app `main_app`, and a third app `third_app`. Let's say you want to override a template named `login.html`. To override this template, create a `login.html` you will save here:

```sh
.
└── your_project
    ├── main_app
    └── third_app
        └── templates
            └── third_app
                └── login.html  <--- save your file here
```

Then, tell Django to look for that location if it needs a template named `login.html` for the app named `third_app`:

```py
# settings.py

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # [...]
        'DIRS': [
            # [...]
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'third_app', 'templates'),
        ],
    }
]
```

That way, `Django` will always look first for that template, before taking the default one.

To properly override the template, just copy/paste the original one, and adapt what you need. Same goes for `static` files used by `third_app`.

Hope that will help!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! Well, i'm already overriding the template, the problem is that this form is not defined in the template. If i override the template and use my own html, i will still see form that i posted in my question

Comment: I don't understand, normally it is not the form object that has the class and styles stuff, but the template and the static files. If you override both template and css stylesheet, you should be good to go. What do you mean "this form is not defined in the template"? When you override the template you are talking about, can you see the changes?

Comment: Take a look to this https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/blob/master/two_factor/templates/two_factor/core/login.html

Comment: As you can see, there isn't a line where 'Username' and 'Password' are defined, the whole form is just imported from something else

Comment: Well, I suggest you to look at the template `two_factor/_wizard_forms.html` as this file is included in the template you just showed me (`{% include "two_factor/_wizard_forms.html" %}`). Maybe it is this template you need to override.

Comment: That is the problem: on that page, there are only four lines, so the template i need to override it's not even that one, this is why i say that i can't find it https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/blob/master/two_factor/templates/two_factor/_wizard_forms.html

Answer (score 0):

The third party app login template is placed in accounts/login. So create a folder named accounts in your templates directory and create login templates inside it, it will override the existing template.