# How to check if session is expired in Django views?

Tags: django, django-views

I am using Django session framework for login and logout functionality in my application. I do have multiple Django views as per business requirements. I have login view where I call authenticate() function to start the session for a user. But,I want to know how do I check whether session is valid when user calls different views. I am planning to implement using following code snippet. Can I someone tell me if this is the correct way of checking whether session is active or expired?

```
def login(request):
  body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
  body = json.loads(body_unicode)
  user_name = body['user_name']
  password = body['password']
  user = authenticate(user_name,password)
  if user is None:
    ...
  else:
    ...

  return JsonResponse(...)

def view_1(request):
  body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
  body = json.loads(body_unicode)
  user_name = body['user_name']
  session_key = body['session_key']

  # is below code a correct way to validate for user session 
  if request.session['user_name'] == user_name and request.session.session_key == session_key:
     print('session active')
  else:
     print('session expired')
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use the `@login_required` decorator? Also why do you have your own login view? It doesn't seem to be doing anything special. You can use the built-in views for authentication and only customize the templates.

Comment: Ok. Sorry, but I am bit new to Django. We have our own login page, can we still use the built-in login view? Are you talking about auth_views?

Comment: By your own login page you mean a custom HTML or a custom authentication logic? HTML can certainly be customized using templates. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439153/django-auth-where-to-put-custom-templates) for an example. You don't need to implement your own login view.